# PCG pseudomaze algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, 2d-games, maze, procedural-generation

I created a set of tiles using photoshop:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to fill a screen of these 80x80 tiles, where most areas are connected. This is to a game board for a pac man style game, not a maze with an entry and exit.

**My only goal here is to never have an opening facing a wall.**

I'm currently doing this by choosing the next tile randomly from a subset based on the last tile, so if the last tile has a wall on the left, then the next tile can't have an opening on the left. I'm also limiting the corners to a smaller subset. This only works for the first row.

My problem is calculating the rest of the rows, which will have to be based on the tile immediately to the left, or immediately to the right. I think this will get cumbersome to build the tables by hand. (not that there is anything wrong with hard work, but inefficient work isn't good).

Current output looks like this:[image]

Here is the code I wrote for getting the allowed next tiles based on the most recent tile on the left:

```
function getallowed(last_tile,x,y) as object

cselect={u : ["u","r","v","rx"]
            v : ["u","d","r","v","rx"]
            l : ["u","d","v","rx"]
            d : ["d","r","v","rx"]
            lx :["u","d","r","v","rx"]
            r : ["lx","ux","dx","h","c"]
            h : ["lx","ux","dx","l","h","c"]
            c : ["lx","ux","dx","l","h","c"]
            ux :["lx","ux","dx","l","h","c"]
            rx :["lx","ux","dx","l","h","c"]
            dx :["lx","ux","dx","l","h","c"]
            ul :["dx","br","ur","ux","lx","h","c"]
            ur :["ul","bl","rx","d","r","u","v"]
            bl :["ur","lx","ux","br","dx","c","h","l"]
            br :["ul","bl","rx","r","u","v","d"]}


toprow=["d","r","h","l","dx","ul","ur"]
'toprow=["d","dx","l","r"]
leftcol=["d","r","v","u","rx","ul","bl"]
rightcol=["d","l","v","u","lx","ur","br"]
bottomrow=["u","r","h","l","ux","bl","br"]



if x=0 then 
    if y=0 then
        ?"LEFTCOL AND TOPROW",x,y,last_tile
        selection=intersect(leftcol,toprow)
    else if y=8 then
        ?"LEFTCOL AND BOTTOMROW",x,y,last_tile
        selection=intersect(leftcol,bottomrow)
    else if y > 0 and y < 8 then
        ?"LEFTCOL AND FLOATING Y" ,x,y,last_tile
        selection=leftcol 'intersect(initsel,leftcol)
    end if
else if x=15 then 
    if y=0 then
        ?"RIGHTCOL AND TOPROW",x,y,last_tile
        selection=intersect(rightcol,toprow)
    else if y=8 then
        ?"RIGHTCOL AND BOTTOMROW",x,y,last_tile
        selection = intersect(rightcol,bottomrow)
    else if y>0 and y<8 then
        initsel = cselect[last_tile]
        ?"RIGHTCOL AND FLOATING Y",x,y,last_tile
        selection=intersect(initsel,rightcol)
    end if

    'x=1, y=0, last_tile= "ul"
else if x > 0 and x < 15 
    if y=0 then
        initsel = cselect[last_tile]
        ?"FLOATING X AND TOPROW",x,y,last_tile
        selection=intersect(initsel,toprow)
        'selection=toprow
    else if y=8 
        initsel = cselect[last_tile]
        ?"FLOATING X AND BOTTOM ROW",x,y,last_tile
        selection=intersect(initsel,bottomrow)
    else if y >0 and y < 8 then
        ?"NO CONDITIONS MATCHED RETURN FULL SET FOR LAST TILE",x,y,last_tile
        selection=cselect[last_tile]
    end if
end if
return selection
end function



function intersect(a, b)
    d = {}
    results = []

    for i = 0 to b.count()-1
        d[b[i]] = true
    end for
    for j = 0 to a.count()-1
        if d[a[j]] <> invalid then
            if d[a[j]] then
                results.push(a[j])
            end if
        end if
    end for
    return results
end function
```

Using my current method I will have to create a table for each of the four directions, and do it by hand.

Does anyone have another suggestion or an algorithm to suggest?

Comment: This *is* a maze; maze generators don't usually work with entry/exit anyway. There are (broadly speaking) two ways of generating mazes: cell-based and wall-based. Try the cell-based approach; create the maze, then use your tiles to draw it.

Comment: By the way: I can't really follow your directions pseudocode. All you need is a set of 15 4-bit values (15, not 16, because you (correctly :) did not include an all-wall cell). Then you can use simple bit algorithms to match existing or not-yet-set walls.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use general maze-generation algorithms, you can try [Wang Tiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile) or more advanced [Herringbone Wang Tiles](http://nothings.org/gamedev/herringbone/index.html).